Supabase logging in is too slow for Nuxt
I am making a simple Nuxt3 and supabase app that simply handles authentication through GitHub. My goal was to have middleware in place to protect pages from users that weren't signed in but when I had this in place, I could never leave the login page. I would click the login button, it would think for a second and then just keep me on the login page.
I tried doing the same auth and middleware setup I've seen in other projects and tutorials and honestly expected it to work first try with how simple it is but was mistaken.
When commenting out the middleware, logging in works but there is about a 2 second delay between when the home page is loaded and the user object is loaded (user object comes from useSupabaseUser composable).
I feel as though this is way too slow and would require some serious workarounds to get the outcome I am looking for while avoiding this lag. Am I doing something wrong or is it just this slow?
Here is the script for pages/login.vue:
const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
const user = useSupabaseUser();

async function githubLogin() {
   const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: "github",
      options: {
         redirectTo: "/confirm",
      },
   });
   if (error) throw error;
}

And here is the code for middleware/auth.ts:
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
   const user = useSupabaseUser();
   if (!user.value) {
      return navigateTo("/login");
   }
});

